# Fetching coordinates from svg with respect to its viewBox coordinate system

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

If I have a svg with this viewBox:

`<svg viewBox = "-10 -10 20 20" version = "1.1"></svg>`

I'm trying to get the coordinates from the svg when I click it.
But I'm trying to get the coordinates with respect to the viewBox of the svg.

So in the example above if I had clicked in the center of the svg the result would be:
`x = 0`
`y = 0`

Atm I have just implemented the basic to get the normal coordinates from the width and height of the svg. But how would I go by getting the coordinates from the "new coordinate system" that the viewbox sets on the svg?

I have access to the [x0 y0 width height] of the viewbox. But they might change and the click to get coordinates should still work.

Here is my basic work for now:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMjpGG?editors=101